# Adding JavaScript Function with arguments to an element from code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Hi Guys I've been dealing with an estrange thing while trying to pass string parameters to a JavaScript function from code behind, this is what I have actually in code behind which is wrong:

`thumbnail = "<a href = 'javascript:RemovePirctureDetail(" + field1 + ",'" + tempname + "');' class='label label-default' rel='tooltip'>Remove</a>";`

So this is the bad result I'm getting in the browser:

```
 <a href="javascript:RemovePirctureDetail(4673," download.jpg');'="" class="label label-default" rel="tooltip" data-original-title="" title="">Remove</a>
```

Meas that for some reason when I try to pass the string parameter, the html comes out bad formatted. The result should looks like this:

```
 <a href="javascript:RemovePirctureDetail(4673, 'download.jpg');" class="label label-default" rel="tooltip" data-original-title="" title="">Remove</a>
```

I tried already send the quotation marks like this /' from code behind, it did not work neither. How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: how are you rendering? Is this on an MVC View or WebForms or...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string thumbnail = "<a href=\"javascript: RemovePirctureDetail(4673, 'download.jpg');\" class=\"label label-default\" rel=\"tooltip\" data-original-title=\"\" title=\"\">Remove</a>";`
```

You need to use `\` to escape the quotes inside, not `/`..

Comment: Yes I meant \, however I was implementing it badly like this \' instead of \".  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With javascript attribute I wouldn't use single quote, because it could be messy

Try to change in this way:

```
thumbnail = "<a href = \"javascript:RemovePirctureDetail(" + field1 + ",'" + tempname + "');\"" class=\"label label-default\" rel=\"tooltip\">Remove</a>";
```

PS: Actually, I would NEVER use single quotes with attributes, it will cause an HTML validation error, HTML is not well formed with single quotes for attributes (although with inspection tools you see double quotes.. because inspection tools have the need to work with a well formed HTML, so if you want to see the real HTML of your page, view the source code (generally the option is on right-click on the page)